# How to fix GPU rendering Bug in Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

My application works well in Android L and all other Android versions, but in Android M preview, it has a lot of pauses during the scrolling of the WebView.

Here are the pictures of Profile GPU rendering in Android L and Android M preview.

[image: Profile GPU rendering in Android L]

[image: Profile GPU rendering in Android M]

From these pictures, you can see Android L run every frame in about 16ms, but Android M run every frame more than 120 ms.

I think the problem maybe in the code
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

if I remove this code, It works fine in Android M.
but it doesn't work well in Android 4.0.4

How could I fix this bug, Will Android M fix this ?